# Parsing pcapng vs pcap file

Tags: libpcap

ALL,

The documentation [here](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_next_ex.3pcap.html) talks about 2 different functions.

Is pcap_next() call for pcap while pcap_next_ex() is for pcapng format? Or both those functions can read both formats?

The page doesn't indicate it.

I have a code that parses pcap file and uses the former call, and I'm just wondering if it will be enough to just check for pcapng file and use the latter call instead.

TIA!!

Answer (score 1):

> Is pcap_next() call for pcap while pcap_next_ex() is for pcapng format?

No.  `pcap_next()` is for applications that don't bother checking for errors, and `pcap_next_ex()` is for applications that do.  To quote the RETURN VALUE section of [the man page](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_next_ex.3pcap.html):

> `pcap_next_ex()` returns 1 if the packet was read without problems, 0 if packets are being read from a live capture and the packet buffer timeout expired, `PCAP_ERROR` if an error occurred while reading the packet, and `PCAP_ERROR_BREAK` if packets are being read from a ``savefile'' and there are no more packets to read from the savefile. If `PCAP_ERROR` is returned, pcap_geterr(3PCAP) or pcap_perror(3PCAP) may be called with *p* as an argument to fetch or display the error text.
>
> `pcap_next()` returns a pointer to the packet data on success, and returns `NULL` if an error occurred, or if no packets were read from a live capture (if, for example, they were discarded because they didn't pass the packet filter, or if, on platforms that support a packet buffer timeout that starts before any packets arrive, the timeout expires before any packets arrive, or if the file descriptor for the capture device is in non-blocking mode and no packets were available to be read), or if no more packets are available in a "savefile." Unfortunately, there is no way to determine whether an error occurred or not.

You should use `pcap_next_ex()`.

> Or both those functions can read both formats?

Yes.  (`pcap_next_ex()` was added before libpcap could even read pcapng files.)

> I have a code that parses pcap file and uses the former call, and I'm just wondering if it will be enough to just check for pcapng file and use the latter call instead.

It would be enough just to use `pcap_next_ex()` regardless of whether the file is a pcap or pcapng file.